# Undelete request

Tags: support, deleted-questions

all. I deleted a question right before someone answered it and now I am trying to undelete it, but can't because I don't have enough reputation. I reposted an identical question on math.stackexchange.com because I thought the question might fit better there.

It's name, in both cases is "Does it matter how you pull marbles out of this vat?"

Could someone please undelete this question for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Done](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31226/930).

In case you wonder about the appropriateness of your question, it is good to ask the community or a moderator, which is what you did in your comment (I deleted it, btw), and *wait some time* before deleting and reposting.

Comment: Super, thanks for the help!

Comment: @enthdegree No problem. Thanks for bringing this to our attention and removing the dup on math.SE.